# API Security - oauth 1 or 2?

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

He guys,

I have designed a 'Pragmatic RESTful' API. Not to Fieldings spec - but aligned to this http://www.restapitutorial.com/ - please leave the what is / isn't a RESTful API debate aside for now...

What I want to know is how to best secure my API. I see that Oauth1.0a is common, but I also see that it is deprecated. What is it that I should be using now? Oauth2.0? Or should I ignore the deprecation and go ahead with Oauth1.0a?

Also, if I am to use either Oauth 1.0 or 2.0, what flow should I be researching for an API?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Oauth 2.0 specification allows you to tailor the security to your needs. You will have to find out what works best for you and your situation if you were to use OAuth 2.0.

Although Hans says that Oauth 2.0 is safest, you must realize that many think most implementations of it are insecure (not because the specification is bad, but because it's so open and loose that people don't properly secure all areas like they should). Oauth 2.0 is more "loose" in the way it approaches the subject. If you look closely, the RFC spec for Oauth 2.0 calls it a "framework" while it calls Oauth 1.0a a "protocol". For that and some other reasons, companies like twitter have stuck with Oauth 1.0a. Although OAuth 2.0 is new, you will have to bring in other specifications, like JWT to secure it properly.

If I wanted to be sure that my API application was secure, I would definitely stick with Oauth 1.0a (tried and tested) unless you absolutely need some feature of Oauth 2.0 for now.

With Oauth1.0a there is really only one way to do things so your question as to "what flow" you should use is pretty much answered there.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 is the successor of OAuth 1.0a and many APIs have started to support it in favor of Auth 1.0a. Also, new developments - such as features that are comparable to the signed requests in OAuth 1.0a, called proof-of-possession tokens - are happening currently in OAuth 2.0 and no development is done on OAuth 1.0. So OAuth 2.0 is your safest bet for the future.